# How to emulate curl -F for facebook graph api batch request in python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am trying to follow the example for batch processing found in:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/batch-requests/

specifically, the curl command:

```
  curl -F 'access_token=____' 
    -F 'batch=[
               {
                "method": "POST",
                "relative_url": "6004251715639",
                "body": "redownload=1&max_bid=35"
               },
               {
                "method": "POST",
                "relative_url": "6004251716039",
                "body": "redownload=1&max_bid=35"
               },
               {
                "method": "POST",
                "relative_url": "6004251715839",
                "body": "redownload=1&max_bid=35"
               }
              ]' https://graph.facebook.com
```

works fine.

When I try to use urllib2 in python, I have no idea how to emulate the "-F" flags.

When it was "-d" for a single request I knew what to do:

```
curl -d  "name=Chm&daily_budget=1000&lifetime_budget=10000
&campaign_status=1" "https://graph.facebook.com/
act_368811234/adcampaigns?access_token=___"
```

I emulated it using the python code:

```
def sendCommand(self, url, dataForPost=None):        
    if dataForPost == None:
        req = urllib2.Request(url)
    else:
        req = urllib2.Request(url, dataForPost)        
    jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
    content = opener.open(req)
    response = content.read()
    return response
```

How can I emulate the -F command above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sendCommand` function should work. The dataForPost is expecting a dictionary. If you pass it the one below it will replicate the -F function for access_token and batch. I am using a `"""` string literal and stripping the whitespace. You could leave it in but urllib2 would try to url-encode it and it could make debugging harder. You might try using the json library for generating the batch value.

```
dataForPost = {'access_token' : '____',  
               'batch' : """[
               {
                "method": "POST",
                "relative_url": "6004251715639",
                "body": "redownload=1&max_bid=35"
               },
               {
                "method": "POST",
                "relative_url": "6004251716039",
                "body": "redownload=1&max_bid=35"
               },
               {
                "method": "POST",
                "relative_url": "6004251715839",
                "body": "redownload=1&max_bid=35"
               }
              ]""".replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace(' ', '')}
```

Comment: Thanks! This Works!!!
Had only to add dataForPost = urllib.urlencode(dataForPost) to get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

For Python,We can use [Facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) for getting the functionality of batch requests and handling pagination of Facebook Graph API.

as per facebook, graph api takes 50 requests at a time but facepy handles that for us i.e we can append as many requests to the list and batch them.

```
from facepy import GraphAPI
access = <access_token>
batch1=[
    {'method': 'GET', 'relative_url': 'me/accounts'}
]
graph = GraphAPI(access)
data= graph.batch(batch1)

for i in data:
    print i
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. It's rather a comment.